# Kibana and elasticsearch regexp doenot work

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7, elasticsearch-7

I'm trying to get exact match of field but unfortunately regexp doesn't
work with me.

I have elasticsearch 7.5.2

Now i'm trying to search inside field for string exactly for example

I have this urlField : /lang1/page1/ and /lang2/page1/ and /lang3/page1/
etc...

i tried to play with the reg to get the above three urls ONLY but Kibana
keep giving me anything contains any of the above example:

but Kibana returns to me results contans also:

/lang1/page4/other/url/?blahblahblah and /hello/this/is/ayman/lang1

but i don't need those i just need the above red urls exactly.

What is the problem here? please advise

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you right, but you can use the `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` from Spring Data Elasticsearch to build a query using the native Elasticsearch query builders.